# how can i fix multicharacter error for a space

Tags: c++, arrays

was solving a question to find max word length in sentence
i used getline for my array and it contain spaces while trying to run this it givs a warning like this how can i avoid this
warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
if(arr[i]=='/0')

```
int n;
char arr[n+1];
cin.getline(arr,n);
int i=0;
int wordlen=0;
int maxi=0;
//the max word length
while(i<=n){
if(arr[i]=='/0')
{

maxi=max(maxi,wordlen);
wordlen=0;
}

else{
    wordlen++;
}i++;
}cout<<maxi;
```

Comment: What is `arr`?  Please post a [mcve].

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: `if(arr[i]=='/0')` => `if(arr[i]=='\0')` you have a simple typo, or misunderstood escaped character literals @Tushar

Comment: `char arr[n+1];` -- If `n` is not `const`, then this is not valid C++ code.

Comment: `int n; char arr[n+1];` -- This is wrong in multiple ways.  First, `char arr[n+1]` is not valid C++, as arrays in C++ must have their size denoted by a constant-expression, not a runtime variable.  Second, even if this syntax were valid, `n` is not initialized.  Let's assume that `n` is initialized -- the declaration of arr should be `std::vector<char> arr(n + 1);`

Comment: `int maxi = 0; std::istringstream strm(arr); std::string word; while (strm >> word) { maxi = std::max(word.size(), maxi; }` -- No need for `wordlen`.

Answer (score -2):

Your array can be sorter than 100 like you took it in your loop, so when your loop was running, it could be overflow and the complier couldn't get that. To fix this one, let try:

```
for(int i=0;i<arr.length();i++)
{
   if(arr[i]=='/0')
   {
     cout<<"gotcha";
   }
}
```

Comment: How does that answer the question? Your code simply replicates the same error. Also there's no such thing like `arr.length()`.